# Download File That Uses Download Attribute With Urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to parse a webpage and download a series of csv files that are in zip folders. When I click on the link on the website, I can download it without any trouble. However whenever I paste the URL into my browser (ie: example.com/file.zip), I get a 400 Bad Request error. I am not sure but I have deduced this issue is caused because the link uses a [download attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

The problem now is when I use urllib.request.urlretrieve to download the zip files, I can not. My code is fairly simple:

```
# Look to a specific folder in my computer
# Compare the zip files in that folder to the zip files on the website
# What ever is on the website, but not on my local machine 
# is added to a dictionary called remoteFiles

for remoteFile in remoteFiles:
  try:
    filename = ntpath.basename(remoteFile)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(remoteFile, filename)
    print('finished downloading: ' + filename)
  except Exception as e:
    print('error with file: ' + filename)
    print(e)
```

[Here is a PasteBin link](http://pastebin.com/9SxXbfJz) to my full .py file. Wherever I run it I get an error:

> HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: first improve your `except` statement: `except Exception as e:` then `print(str(e))` will tell you why it fails (and you can post the stacktrace here to improve your post at the same time :))

Comment: Ok, I updated my original post, it's a `HTTP Error 400: Bad Request` error.

Comment: can you create a simple reproducer instead of the full code?

Comment: After looking into it a little more, I don't think my code is the issue but rather the URL I'm pointing towards. It may be that the website is some how  disguising the files URL's, though I'm no expert.